How can I deploy Wordpress to Azure resources, not using the "wordpress on app service"
I would like to create a Linux Web App, My SQL database, Managed Identity and Blob Storage in Azure.
Then download wordpress from their site, configure the files and use DevOps CICD to deploy by FTP and run any DB scripts.
All I see is based on "wordpress on app service", and I can't imagine it would be very difficult to make it work without it. When I develop a site in dotnet all I do is transfer files and set some environment variables.

Then what kind of answers do you want? Step-by-step tutorials?

Tutorials would be great, but any documentation on how to make wordpress use a managed identity to connect to mysql, or how to configure wordpress by editing files instead of using the web interface, etc would be helpful.

Those belong to search engines. Asking such on this site is considered off-topic.

Well, as I mentioned, I can't find anything (using search engines) to go on that isn't based on "wordpress on app service". Also, if I ask gemini or chatgpt, I get stuff that doesn't work. So I come here to ask real people for help.
